# How to translate the following predicates with quantifiers into English?

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Q(x, z) = "x has z followers on Twitter"

Universe of discourse for x, y = all students
Universe of discourse for z = non-negative integers

How would I properly write the following in English?

$$\forall y \exists x \; Q(x,y)$$

I know $$\forall x \exists y \; Q(x,y)$$ would be: everyone has at least one follower on Twitter.
The inverted variables is what's confusing me.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are students neither of these has  a meaning. When you say $y$ followers you are taking $y$ to be an integer, not a student.

Comment: You're right. I copied incorrectly - edited!

Comment: $Q(x,y)$ still does not make sense

Comment: I suspect that there is a language barrier here (*be it mathematical language, or actual spoken language*) which is causing issues.  I would think what you really mean to be talking about is $Q(x,y)$ being the statement that $y$ is a twitter-follower of $x$.  In such a situation, you would have $\forall y \exists x Q(x,y)$ would read "*for every $y$ there exists an $x$ such that $y$ is a twitter follower of $x$*", or worded another way, it would mean that ever person has at least one person that they are a follower of.

Comment: Compare that to $\forall x \exists y Q(x,y)$ which reads that everyone has at least one twitter follower.

Comment: Alternatively, if you really do mean for the second argument to be a non-negative integer, then it would read $\forall y \exists x Q(x,y)$ reads "for all non-negative integers $y$ there exists a student $x$ such that the student has $y$ twitter followers" (*which of course isn't possible in real life, as that would imply there is a student with $10^{100}$ twitter followers, many orders of magnitude more than the number of people alive*).  On the other hand, $\forall x \exists y Q(x,y)$ would mean every person has some positive integer number of twitter followers.

Comment: This is the exact question: Let P(x, y) denote "x follows y on Twitter", and let Q(x, z) denote "x has z followers on Twitter, where the universe of discourse for the variables x and y is all students, and the universe of discourse for the variable x is the non-negative integers.

Comment: $\forall x \exists y \,Q(x,y)$ means that everyone has **zero** or more followers, since the universe of discourse for the numbers of followers is the set of non-negative integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that the universe of discourse for $x$ is ‘all students’, and for $y$ is the non-negative integers...**

As you say, $\forall x \exists y Q(x,y)$ means ‘for every student $x$, there is some $y$ which is the number of followers $x$ has on Twitter’. More naturally, this is ‘all students have a (non-negative integer) number of followers on Twitter’.

$\forall y \exists x Q(x,y)$ could be translated as ‘for all non-negative integers $y$ there exists a student $x$ who has $y$ followers on Twitter’. More naturally, this is ‘For any non-negative integer, there is a student who has this number of followers on Twitter’. So, for example, there is a student with $3$ followers. There is also a student with $5378245$ followers. The same goes for all other non-negative integers.